# Django Channels not receiving the event raised from library

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

This is my Consumer Class.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer,AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
import asyncio
import random

import json
class TradeSession(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        print("In Consumer Now")
        self.room_name = "test_consumer"
        self.room_group_name = "test_consumer_group"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("Disconnected Now")
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        raise channels.exceptions.StopConsumer()



    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        print("Data Recieverd")
        pass


    async def send_number(self, event):
        print("in Send number Send event",event)
        number = event["price"]
        print("Actuly sending now ",number)
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"price": number}))
```

Following Is my Communicator library from where I am trying to raise an event.

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import asyncio


class Communicator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def send_data_to_channel_layer(self, data, group_name):
        group_name = "test_consumer_group"
        print("In library sending data")
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        print("Sendiong now to group",group_name)
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(group_name, {
            "type": "send.number",
            "price": data['price'],
        })
        # print("Message sent to group")
```

In the logs I can see till the point - Sendiong now to group",group_name
And after this log I see nothing on the console

To add to to this

1. My websocket is working fine And i have verified that from the client as well
2. I am using redis-channel for the internal communication for channals
3. This is the configuration for the same

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Also I have verified that redis is runing on the same port on my local and I am trying all this on my local only
[image]

I am clueless to what is it that I am missing here.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this I am using wrong function name channel_layer.send
it should be channel_layer.group_send